# Input Text Not Taking Value ASP .NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, html.textboxfor

I'm using data tables plugin and the fact is that I have thousand of rows so I've implemented Server Processing approach. The thing is that one of the columns has a text box, but given that I'm generating the info in the controller I create that field in there.

This is how I define the element in the controller:

```
<input class='form-control' data-val='true' data-val-number='El campo Número de Protocolo debe ser un número.' data-val-range='El campo Número de Protocolo debe ser un número entero.' data-val-range-max='2147483647' data-val-range-min='1' id='donaciones_" + i +"__numeroProtocolo' name='donaciones[" + i + "].numeroProtocolo' type='text' />
```

In my viewModel one of the fields is a `List<Donacion>` named donaciones, and one of the attributes of a Donacion object is "numeroProtocolo". The text box seems to be rendered ok, but when I type on it, the "value" property doesn't change. No matter what I write on it, value property doesn't change.

This is what it looks like in the view, when rendered:

```
<input id="donaciones_0__numeroProtocolo" class="form-control" type="text" name="donaciones[0].numeroProtocolo" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-range-max="2147483647" data-val-range="El campo Número de Protocolo debe ser un número entero." data-val-number="El campo Número de Protocolo debe ser un número." data-val="true"></input>
```

Any ideas why can it be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was wrong. I live the answer here for future reference. I was generating different names for each text input depending on the pages. For example, if I am displaying 10 rows, names for page 1 will be `donations[0],donations[1],...,donations[9]` for the page 2
will be `donations[10],donations[11],...,donations[19]`. The problem is that with server side processing after each ajax call the table redraws, and you lose the previous elements with name from `0,1... to 9` so you only have now the ones that goes from `10,11... to 19` and mvc can't return a list that have elements starting in an index different from 0. That's why it wasn't working.